# Appending to file with sudo access

Tags: linux, bash, automation

I am trying to append line to an existing file owned by root and I have to do this task with about 100 servers. So I created `servers.txt` with all the IPs and the `ntp.txt` file which will have the lines that I need to append. I am executing the following script and I am not achieving what I am trying to. Can someone please suggest what needs to be corrected?

```
!/bin/bash
servers=`cat servers.txt`;
for i in $servers;
do
  cat ntp.txt | ssh root@${i} sudo sh -c "cat >>ntp.conf""
done
```

Comment: Why do you need to use sudo if you're already logged in as root?

Comment: Do you want to append to `ntp.conf` in root's home directory or do you want to append to `/etc/ntp.conf` ?

Comment: Apart from the file path, that does look ok. Though you could just do `ssh root@$i "cat >> /path/to/ntp.conf" < ntp.txt` -- no need for `sudo`, `sh` or `cat`.

Comment: @mark plotnick i need to append to /etc/ntp.conf

Answer (score 1):

Here are some issues; not sure I found all of them.

1. The shebang line lacks the `#` which is significant and crucial.
2. There is no need to read the server names into a variable, and in addition to wasting memory, you are exposing yourself to a number of potential problems; see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor
3. [Unless you specifically *require* the shell to do whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion on a value,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) put it in double quotes (or even single quotes, but this inhibits variable expansion, which you still want).
4. If you are logging in as `root`, no need to explicitly `sudo`.
5. `ssh` runs a shell for you; no need to explicitly `sh -c` your commands.
6. On the other hand, you want to avoid running a root shell if you can.  A common way to get to append to a file without having to spawn a shell just to be able to redirect is to use `tee -a` (just drop the `-a` to overwrite instead of append).  Also printing the file to standard output is an undesired effect (some would say the main effect rather than side effect of `tee` but let's just not go there) so you often redirect to `/dev/null` to avoid having the text also spill onto your screen.
7. You probably want to avoid a [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) if only just to avoid having somebody point out to you that it's useless.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r server; do
do
  ssh you@"$server" sudo tee -a /etc/ntp.conf <ntp.txt >/dev/null
done <servers.txt
```

I changed the code to log in as `you` but it's of course something you will need to adapt to suit your environment. (If you log in as yourself, you usually just `ssh server` without explicitly specifying a user name.)

As per your comment, I also added a full path to the destination file `/etc/ntp.conf`

A more disciplined approach to server configuration is to use something like CFengine2 to manage configurations.